# Different listPreference background Color on two android versions

Tags: android, android-layout

styles.xml :

```
<resources
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_repeat</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name="Main" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"></activity>
```

Main.java :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and on main.java i have a listPreference. background color of listpreference is white on android 2.3.5 and is blue on android 4.0.4. and now i'm confused on font color of list preference items.